# Do we need a coffee-caffeine tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, specific-tag

Do we need a tag for [coffee-caffeine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coffee-caffeine), or should this tag just be merged into [food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food)?

It seems to me that neither coffee nor caffeine has a special place in Jewish life and learning, unlike, say, [grapes-wine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grapes-wine) and [bread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bread), which have special statuses, halachic definitions, aggadic implications, etc.

On the other hand, we do seem to have a bunch of coffee-related questions.

Comment: +1, thanks for asking this question.

Comment: @msh210 Re: your edits - If the word "really" was inserted into the title (consistent with what I meant), would you switch back to [meta-tag:status-completed]?  :)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, ah, whatever. I was just tagging it so people would see it was already acted upon and discussion pretty much closed (not that people can't voice further opinions). Which tag it is doesn't matter so much. `:-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have several coffee-related questions, but I don't think coffee is really central to them.  (One of them is about a mug, for instance.)  Absent either that centrality or coffee-specific considerations, I don't think we need this tag.  Existing tags cover these questions adequately.

Comment: Seeing no objection to this position, which is mine as well, I've done the merge.

Comment: +1, thanks for stepping forward and taking initiative.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee does have a very interesting and storied history in Jewish ritual. Access to coffee in the 17th century was a major catalyst in the spread and growing popularity of late-night ritual (such as the Tikkun Leil Shavuot) which previously were acts of individual piety and became much more popular (parallel to the spread of and popularization of the Kabbalah at the same time). See Robert Bonfil, "Coffee, Coffeehouses, and the Nocturnal Rituals of Early Modern Jewry" (AJS Review 14.1).

Comment: That's fascinating, and I feel more enlightened knowing it, but I'm not sure that it's sufficient to justify a whole tag.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16703/759